# white spaces while copying password into password filed

Tags: python-3.x

From experience I know that sometimes while copying and  pasting a password into the password filed a white space is copied along with the password and this is causing errors (I don't know how common this is, but it happens). Now I'm learning Python (no previous programming experience) and came across `rstrip()` `lstrip()` and `strip()` method. What would be the "right" way to handle such situations ?

Any inside is highly appreciated.

Comment: It depends on whether leading or trailing whitespace would be considered part of the password or not. Most would probably guess that it wouldn’t, but then again, why wouldn’t it? A space is a valid character (or should be), probably at any location.

Comment: @poke That's interesting. I have never seen a white space being used but I like the idea. Will definitely dig into it. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

I would use `strip()` to strip both sides :-) I think it's very annoying when you copy paste a password and it's not accepted because you mis-copied with some extra blank characters.

Comment: But should we do this ? What about simply rejecting the password telling that it is incorrect ?

Comment: Indeed, it's annoying, specially for the end-users, but I'm concerned more with the security approach of the problem rather than users comfort.

Comment: @adam86 its a usability issue and bad usability breeds bad security. Merely stripping spaces does not preclude spaces inside the password. Disallowing 1 character at the ends is minor in comparison IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not doing anything. I don't believe in editing any password submissions, except for sanitizing to prevent security risks.